# Trac wiki and Visual Paradigm for UML

Tags: uml, wiki, trac, visual-paradigm

Any tips how to present documentation coming out of Visual Paradigm for UML on Trac wiki in most efficient way? Is there a way to embed the tables on wiki page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually in Trac no way of docs presentation coming out of VP.

I use a workaround which is quite practical for me:

1. make a screenshot of changed diagrams in VP and save them as .png files
2. copy the image files to a path I defined an Apache webserver Location for in httpd.conf:

   `<Location /doc>
   ...
   </Location>`

   `Alias /doc "//your.local.imagefileserver.org/anysubdir/doc"`
3. then I just use image wiki links to that location in my wiki page, e.g. [[Image(//doc/UML/diagram1.png)]]

This way, after changes to diagrams, I can replace the images on disk without touching the wiki, and the wiki shows the latest on page reload then.